# Web Api 2 run-time error when trying to use .netstandard 2 assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-standard

I have an Asp.net WebApi 2 site referencing .net 4.6.1. Up till now 
the site was referencing a PCL assembly (portable class library), for compatibility with UWP & Xamarin, without issues. Now I am trying to change that PCL to a NetStandard2.0 assembly, as recommended, but am receiving an error at site start up.

The error is below -

> Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
>   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same thing.  I  added this to my web.config and it worked.

`<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>`

Oh the joys of Binding Redirects.

Comment: Worked for me as well in 2019