# Webapi methodnotfound exception get_MessageHandlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have added two custom message handlers in my web api 2 application as shown here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Then registeted them in Register method as,

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogHandler());
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HeaderHandler());
```

Getting this error on startup:

```
Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1 
System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()'.
```

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: I am getting this exact same error but the solution ain't working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720729/web-api-2-run-time-error-when-trying-to-use-netstandard-2-assembly

Comment: Did you try the solution provided in that post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching for hours I realised this happened due to adding a  reference to .NET standard library project.

As soon as I removed the other project this error disappeared and application is running fine.

Also important point to note is, the issue simulates only when I add message handlers of my own and reference to a .Net standard library.

Comment: Thanks man - had the same issue with a reference to a .Net standard library.

Comment: Thank you. I had been searching for post like this for several hours. Now problem is solved.

Answer (score 9):

I found the root cause of this issue to be .net standard references often bring in references to different versions of packages like System.Net.Http as a dependency for the package.

I ran into this when I updated my StackExchange.Redis. It ran fine locally but when deployed to the server it would crash.

For me to fix this I added a binding redirect for System.Net.Http

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: nice - we needed this for a system blocked and couldn't redo the references.. so props to you and we owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I changed the way I referenced a number of Aspose assemblies from locally ref to nuget.

The nuget packages had several dependencies which were pulled into my project.
One of these dependencies was System.Text.Encoding.CodePages v4.4.0, which in turn appear to have pulled .NETStandard assemblies into my project.

The web-app (asp.net mvc 461) ran fine on my dev box, however, on the IIS (W2012) I got an error similar to the one mentioned here.

I removed System.Text.Encoding.CodePages v4.4.0 and it worked.
Please see: https://forum.aspose.com/t/why-we-can-not-download-zip-like-we-have-in-the-past/176767/3

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I upgraded the Azure Cosmos DB SDK from v2 to v3, it added .NET Standard 2.0 libraries.

To fix this, I simply removed the binding redirect that got added to the web.config file automatically after the package upgrade:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.3" newVersion="4.1.1.3" /> <!-- Delete this line -->
  </dependentAssembly>
```